# Installing Z3 + Python on Windows

Tags: z3

I am having some hard time getting the Z3 Python frontend to work on Windows 7 with Z3 version 4.3.0 from codeplex.  The older version 4.1.2 that was distributed as an MSI file works fine on my Windows 7.

First, I cannot use the source code from codeplex to build Z3 because I don't have Visual studio Command Prompt (do I really need it?).  So I download the binary file 32 bit version and add that directory to my PYTHONPATH.  This allows me to do  `import z3` , but  I cannot use it any further because of the error `Z3Exception: 'init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH) must be invoked before using Z3-python'` .    The file `z3.dll`  is not included in the download file.

I have no problem setting Z3 v4.3 on my Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Express should be enough to compile Z3 and is available for free from Microsoft, [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products). However, it's not a requirement that Z3 be compiled from scratch to use Z3Py.

Starting with version 4.3.0, the DLL is now called libz3.dll and I just verified that it is indeed included in the download from Codeplex and it executes fine when I add it to PYTHONPATH. I can imagine that what went wrong in your case is that you added the directory C:...\z3-4.3.0-x86 to PYTHONPATH, while it is necessary that C:...\z3-4.3.0-x86\bin be added (note the \bin in the end).

Comment: hi Chris,  actually I did add the \bin directory (that's why I was able to do the import z3 fine).   I also tried z3.init("libz3.dll")  but I believe there was some error.   I don't have access to my Win machine now but I can post the error tomorrow.  Does it work for you when you do z3.init("libz3.dll") ?

Comment: Great! Thanks for the information. There is another thing I forgot to mention: It depends on what version of Python is installed; I believe the x64 version also requires that the x64 DLL is used.

Comment: Christoph is correct. If we have Python x64, then we must use the the x64 Z3 DLL. Note that, if we have a 64 bits machine, but we are using a 32-bit Python (very common scenario), then we must use the 32 bits Z3 DLL.